# Object initialization begins with "!"

Tags: php

I just found
`!$foo = new Bar($var, $var2);`
part of PHP code. What "!" means?

Comment: what is in the code around it? Seems like a strange thing to do unless you want to us it in a conditional statement. i.e. "if this class initializes, then don't do this"

Comment: I think you can convert it to `@` :)

Comment: @ is for suppressing errors and A) has nothing to do with this and B) is very bad practice.

Comment: there is no any code around, just a single string. I think it's just useless typo. Anyway, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ! is merely a negation and useless in this example.

Answer (score 1):

It means nothing special. I think there is a typo.

Considering the following code:

```
$foo = new Bar($var, $var1);
var_dump(!$foo);        // bool(false)
var_dump($foo == true); // bool(true)
```

- Casting an object to a boolean will always result in `true`.
- Comparing an object with another object without `===` will always result in `true`.

So using a negation on an object in the left part of an assignment hasn't any effect here.

Answer (score 1):

In this context it means absolutely nothing.

`!` is the "logical not" operator, it converts something that evaluates to `TRUE` to `FALSE` and vice versa. It has no other special meaning in PHP.

It only really makes sense as part of a boolean test or assignment, for example:

```
$false = FALSE;
if (!$false) {
  // This code will be executed
}

$true = !$false;
// $true will now be TRUE
```

In the context used in you example it makes no sense as instantiating an object [will only ever do one of two things](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.new):

1. Return an object - every instance of every object will evaluate to `TRUE` in a boolean test, with one exception: an empty `SimpleXMLElement`.
2. Throw an exception. In this case the variable to which the new instance would have been assigned will still have it's previous value (which might evaluate to false) but execution will leave the current procedure immediately, so the test would never be evaluated.